# show stackwidget in qt and hide it

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display in button click a stackwidget with some information.

However, having trouble to do this.
I have 2 files : mainwindow.cpp and ppualert.cpp and i want to open the file ppualert while the user click the button in mainwindow. (something like div in html)

my main problem : the stackwidget is shown allways and his buttons does not response.

what am i do wrong?
BTW i can't open it in another different window cause i am workin with qt linux embedded and eglfs plugin, it's write the widgets straight to frame buffer and limited to one window.

here is the code:

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ppualert.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);

 ppu = new ppuAlert(this);
 connect(ppu,&ppuAlert::ppuDialogClosed,this,&MainWindow::onPPUDialogClosed);
 ui->swPPU->addWidget(new ppuAlert);
 ui->swPPU->hide();
}


void MainWindow::on_btnShowPPU_clicked()
{
   ui->swPPU->setCurrentIndex(0);
   ui->swPPU->show();
}
void MainWindow::onPPUDialogClosed()
{
   ui->swPPU->hide();
}
```

ppualert.cpp:

```
#include "ppualert.h"
#include "ui_ppualert.h"

ppuAlert::ppuAlert(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::ppuAlert)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

ppuAlert::~ppuAlert()
{
  delete ui;
}

void ppuAlert::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
   emit ppuDialogClosed();
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ppualert.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();
  ppuAlert *ppu;
public slots:
  void on_btnShowPPU_clicked();
  void onPPUDialogClosed();
private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

ppualert.h:

```
#ifndef PPUALERT_H
#define PPUALERT_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ppuAlert;
}

class ppuAlert : public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit ppuAlert(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~ppuAlert();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

private:
   Ui::ppuAlert *ui;
signals:
   void ppuDialogClosed();
};

#endif // PPUALERT_H
```

Comment: How do you know the slot handling the button press is called ? You haven't connected the button clicked() signal to anything, so it won't do anything when you click it.

Comment: @VincentFourmond isn't it already done automagically in QtDesigner?

Comment: @Miki - you right this is done automaticlly for me

Comment: Possibly, but your code doesn't show it, so I'm left to guess. Especially when you say that the slot never gets executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ppu = new ppuAlert(this);` Passing the `MainWindow` parent of `ppuAlert` will embed the `ppuAlert ui` on the `MainWindow ui`.
2. Change it to `ppu = new ppuAlert();`
   Now you can add `ppuAlert` to the stacked widget and hide or show it.
3. To hide the stackWidget , Add this in MainWindow
   `connect(ppu,SIGNAL(ppuDialogClosed()),this,SLOT(ppuDialogClosed()));`
4. Change

   ```
   void MainWindow::onPPUDialogClosed()
   {
   ui->swPPU->setHidden(true);
   }
   ```
5. Change this `ui->swPPU->addWidget(new ppuAlert);` to `ui->swPPU->addWidget(ppu);`

Comment: techneaz  Thanks, I tried that and its really added to my stackwidget and i can show it but how can i hide it? ths signal of the button in the ppualert is emited but the slot never execute. i want to hide the stackwidget in the button click (or while clicking outside the stackwidget)

Comment: Try `swPPU.setHidden(bool)`.

Comment: Add a **checkable** button outside the stack widget and link the above slot to the button `clicked(bool)` signal

Comment: techneaz the requirement is to display the button inside the stackwidget... i dont understand  your solution ...

Comment: See the edited answer. Sorry I thought a button outside when you said **"or while clicking outside the stackwidget"**

Comment: I changed as you said but still the slot not execute. maybe i miss something here ???